# Unsuccessfully saving data and image files into database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have an form which have to run store function in my `VerificationController.php` and edit data in users table and create record in verifications table and must save two images into specific folders, but after I'll send ajax request, nothing happens. I also tried `dd()` function on some variables, but nothing happens too.

My `store` function:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $request->validate([
      'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
      'lastname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
      'id_front' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
      'id_back' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
    ]);
    
    
    
    if($request->hasFile('id_front') && $request->hasFile('id_back')) {
       $path_front = $request->file('id_front')->store('user_verifications/front/'.$request->user()->id);
       $path_back = $request->file('id_back')->store('user_verifications/back/'.$request->user()->id);
       
       
       $user = auth()->user();
       $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->first();
       $user->verified = "yes";
       $user->save();
       
          
       $verification = new Verification();
       $verification->user_id = $user->id;
       $verification->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
       $verification->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
       $verification->country = $request->input('country');
       $verification->id_front_path = $path_front;
       $verification->id_back_path = $path_back;
       $verification->save();
          
       DB:commit();

    }
```

And my JS part of `Verify.vue` (the view) file:

```
data() {
        return {
            verificationForm: this.$inertia.form({
                firstname: '',
                lastname: '',
                country: 'USA',
                options: [
                  { text: 'United States', value: 'USA' },
                  { text: 'United Kingdom', value: 'UK' },
                  { text: 'Afghanistan', value: 'Afghanistan' },
                  { text: 'Albania', value: 'Albania' },
                  { text: 'Algeria', value: 'Algeria' },
                  { text: 'American Samoa', value: 'AmericanSamoa' },
                  { text: 'Andorra', value: 'Andorra' },
                  { text: 'Angola', value: 'Angola' },
                  { text: 'Anguilla', value: 'Anguilla' },
                  { text: 'Antigua and Barbuda', value: 'AntiguaAndBarbuda' },
                  { text: 'Argentina', value: 'Argentina' },
                  { text: 'Armenia', value: 'Armenia' },
                  { text: 'Australia', value: 'Australia' },
                  { text: 'Austria', value: 'Austria' },
                  { text: 'Azerbaijan', value: 'Azerbaijan' },
                  { text: 'Bahamas', value: 'Bahamas' },
                  { text: 'Bahrain', value: 'Bahrain' },
                  { text: 'Bangladesh', value: 'Bangladesh' },
                  { text: 'Barbados', value: 'Barbados' },
                  { text: 'Belarus', value: 'Belarus' },
                  { text: 'Belgium', value: 'Belgium' },
                  { text: 'Belize', value: 'Belize' },
                  { text: 'Bolivia', value: 'Bolivia' },
                  { text: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', value: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina' },
                  { text: 'Botswana', value: 'Botswana' },
                  { text: 'Brazil', value: 'Brazil' },
                  { text: 'Bulgaria', value: 'Bulgaria' },
                  { text: 'Cambodia', value: 'Cambodia' },
                  { text: 'Cameroon', value: 'Cameroon' },
                  { text: 'Canada', value: 'Canada' },
                  { text: 'Chad', value: 'Chad' },
                  { text: 'Chile', value: 'Chile' },
                  { text: 'China', value: 'China' },
                  { text: 'Colombia', value: 'Colombia' },
                  { text: 'Congo', value: 'Congo' },
                  { text: 'Costa Rica', value: 'Costa Rica' },
                  { text: 'Croatia', value: 'Croatia' },
                  { text: 'Cuba', value: 'Cuba' },
                  { text: 'Cyprus', value: 'Cyprus' },
                  { text: 'Czechia', value: 'Czechia' },
                  { text: 'Denmark', value: 'Denmark' },
                  { text: 'Dominican Republic', value: 'Dominican Republic' },
                  { text: 'Ecuador', value: 'Ecuador' },
                  { text: 'Egypt', value: 'Egypt' },
                  { text: 'Estonia', value: 'Estonia' },
                  { text: 'Ethiopia', value: 'Ethiopia' },
                  { text: 'Finland', value: 'Finland' },
                  { text: 'France', value: 'France' },
                  { text: 'Germany', value: 'Germany' },
                  { text: 'Ghana', value: 'Ghana' },
                  { text: 'Greece', value: 'Greece' },
                  { text: 'Guatemala', value: 'Guatemala' },
                  { text: 'Guyana', value: 'Guyana' },
                  { text: 'Haiti', value: 'Haiti' },
                  { text: 'Honduras', value: 'Honduras' },
                  { text: 'Hong Kong', value: 'Hong Kong' },
                  { text: 'Hungary', value: 'Hungary' },
                  { text: 'Iceland', value: 'Iceland' },
                  { text: 'India', value: 'India' },
                  { text: 'Indonesia', value: 'Indonesia' },
                  { text: 'Iran', value: 'Iran' },
                  { text: 'Iraq', value: 'Iraq' },
                  { text: 'Ireland', value: 'Ireland' },
                  { text: 'Israel', value: 'Israel' },
                  { text: 'Italy', value: 'Italy' },
                  { text: 'Jamaica', value: 'Jamaica' },
                  { text: 'Japan', value: 'Japan' },
                  { text: 'Jordan', value: 'Jordan' },
                  { text: 'Kazakhstan', value: 'Kazakhstan' },
                  { text: 'Kenya', value: 'Kenya' },
                  { text: 'Kuwait', value: 'Kuwait' },
                  { text: 'Kyrgyzstan', value: 'Kyrgyzstan' },
                  { text: 'Latvia', value: 'Latvia' },
                  { text: 'Lebanon', value: 'Lebanon' },
                  { text: 'Liechtenstein', value: 'Liechtenstein' },
                  { text: 'Luxembourg', value: 'Luxembourg' },
                  { text: 'Malaysia', value: 'Malaysia' },
                  { text: 'Maldives', value: 'Maldives' },
                  { text: 'Malta', value: 'Malta' },
                  { text: 'Mexico', value: 'Mexico' },
                  { text: 'Moldova', value: 'Moldova' },
                  { text: 'Monaco', value: 'Monaco' },
                  { text: 'Mongolia', value: 'Mongolia' },
                  { text: 'Mozambique', value: 'Mozambique' },
                  { text: 'Namibia', value: 'Namibia' },
                  { text: 'Nepal', value: 'Nepal' },
                  { text: 'Netherlands', value: 'Netherlands' },
                  { text: 'New Zealand', value: 'New Zealand' },
                  { text: 'Niger', value: 'Niger' },
                  { text: 'Nigeria', value: 'Nigeria' },
                  { text: 'Norway', value: 'Norway' },
                  { text: 'Oman', value: 'Oman' },
                  { text: 'Pakistan', value: 'Pakistan' },
                  { text: 'Panama', value: 'Panama' },
                  { text: 'Paraguay', value: 'Paraguay' },
                  { text: 'Peru', value: 'Peru' },
                  { text: 'Philippines', value: 'Philippines' },
                  { text: 'Poland', value: 'Poland' },
                  { text: 'Portugal', value: 'Portugal' },
                  { text: 'Puerto Rico', value: 'Puerto Rico' },
                  { text: 'Qatar', value: 'Qatar' },
                  { text: 'Romania', value: 'Romania' },
                  { text: 'Russian Federation', value: 'Russian Federation' },
                  { text: 'Saudi Arabia', value: 'Saudi Arabia' },
                  { text: 'Serbia', value: 'Serbia' },
                  { text: 'Seychelles', value: 'Seychelles' },
                  { text: 'Singapore', value: 'Singapore' },
                  { text: 'Slovakia', value: 'Slovakia' },
                  { text: 'Slovenia', value: 'Slovenia' },
                  { text: 'Somalia', value: 'Somalia' },
                  { text: 'South Africa', value: 'South Africa' },
                  { text: 'Spain', value: 'Spain' },
                  { text: 'Sri Lanka', value: 'Sri Lanka' },
                  { text: 'Sudan', value: 'Sudan' },
                  { text: 'Sweden', value: 'Sweden' },
                  { text: 'Switzerland', value: 'Switzerland' },
                  { text: 'Tanzania', value: 'Tanzania' },
                  { text: 'Thailand', value: 'Thailand' },
                  { text: 'Tunisia', value: 'Tunisia' },
                  { text: 'Turkey', value: 'Turkey' },
                  { text: 'Ukraine', value: 'Ukraine' },
                  { text: 'United Arab Emirates', value: 'United Arab Emirates' },
                  { text: 'Uruguay', value: 'Uruguay' },
                  { text: 'Venezuela', value: 'Venezuela' },
                  { text: 'Vietnam', value: 'Vietnam' },
                  { text: 'Yemen', value: 'Yemen' },
                  { text: 'Zambia', value: 'Zambia' },
                  { text: 'Zimbabwe', value: 'Zimbabwe' },
                ],
                id_front: this.id_front,
                id_back: this.id_back,
            }, {
                bag: 'createVerification',
                resetOnSuccess: false,
            }),
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createVerification() {
            this.verificationForm.post('/user/verify', {
                preserveScroll: true,
            });
        }
    }
```

Edit: 1 [I finally figure out on this error in Google Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrbZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean in the words "**nothing happens**"?

If you mean that files (`id_back`, `id_front`) are not in request files, maybe you forgot `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in you form?

Comment: nothing happens -> I mean that will send ajax request is empty and no changes in database (user will not have changed verified column in DB), no record in verifications table, and no file will be saved..